# How to support push notification in safari on a flutter webapp

Tags: flutter, apple-push-notifications, flutter-web, safari-push-notifications

I have a flutter project which is running on iOS, Android and Web.

Now my challenge is to support push notification in Safari browser (webapp flutter).
I should be able to send custom payload in push notification.

I have gone though the below official documentation, but not getting how to pass custom payload with this approach and also there is NO CALLBACK defined to handle the push notification

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NotificationProgrammingGuideForWebsites/PushNotifications/PushNotifications.html

Please help me out.

Comment: If you are using Firebase Cloud Messaging, it won't work on Safari, [see here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/environments-js-sdk). And Safari [does not support Push API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Push_API).

Comment: I am not using FCM here, @PeterKoltai

Comment: [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NotificationProgrammingGuideForWebsites/PushNotifications/PushNotifications.html) I am referring this link to support push in safari. But here they are not giving any callback to handle push, also we cannot add any custom data in payload @PeterKoltai

Comment: Safari 16, coming soon in macOS Ventura will be adding support for the Web Push API.

Comment: https://firebase.blog/posts/2023/08/fcm-for-safari and [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G6n4FxuhiJo)